# Standard way to pass non-critical errors in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

When working with Error objects in NodeJS, there is the standard 'error' event that can be emitted by EventEmitters, which gets automatically turned into a Thrown error if it's not handled. But what about varying levels of error severity (i.e. "info" or "notice" errors vs. "warning" or "critical"). As far as I can see, there's not a `type` property on the default Error object. Is there any existing standard way to pass/handle errors of various severities? I'm thinking of implementing my own standard for my modules such that listeners would be like:

```
myThing.on('error', function(err) {
  if (err.severity & (ERR_WARNING | ERR_CRITICAl)) {
    console.log("Critical Failure!", err);
    proces.exit(0);
  }
});
```

Meaning they could set their own debugging level and ignore errors that didn't meet that threshold. Does something like this already exist as a standard?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is use another event name for non-critical errors (like `warning` or so). Also you can implement your own "subclass" of `Error` like this:

```
var inherits = require('util').inherits;

function MyError (message, severity) {
  this.name = 'MyError';
  this.severity = severity;
  this.message = message;
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, MyError);
}

inherits(MyError, Error);
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any existing standard way to pass/handle errors of various severities?

Yes, do a `console.error("something is wrong")`. This way your app will continue to operate normally, but will output warnings to stderr ensuring that people will look into it eventually.